# Covariance function of Brownian motion process: $Y(t) = X^2(t)$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, covariance

> What is the covariance function of the following process? $Y(t) = X^2(t)$, $t \ge 0$, where $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion with variance parameter $\sigma^2$.

I note that $$E(Y(t)) = E(X^2(t)) = \text{Var}(X) + E(X(t))^2 = t + 0 = t$$

and

$$\text{Cov} (Y(t), Y(s)) = E(X^2(t)X^2(s)) - E(X^2(t))E(X^2(s)) = E(X^2(t)X^2(s)) - ts$$

If it were $E(X(t)X(s))$, I could have solved it using $X(t) = X(t) - X(s) + X(s)$, but this case it confuses me because $X_s$ are squared.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't format your question properly, then it will receive downvotes (simply because it is hard to read). So please take a look at the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Note that the variance parameter is $\sigma^2$, not 1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually writing $X_t = X_t-X_s+X_s$ is a good idea - there are some more terms than "usual", but this is not too bad. Note that

$$X_t^2 X_s^2 = ((X_t-X_s)+X_s)^2 X_s^2 = (X_t-X_s)^2 X_s^2 + 2 (X_t-X_s) X_s^3 + X_s^4.$$

Use the fact that $X_t-X_s$ and $X_s$ are independent to conclude that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t^2 X_s^2) = \mathbb{E}((X_t-X_s)^2) \mathbb{E}(X_s^2)+2 \mathbb{E}(X_t-X_s) \mathbb{E}(X_s^3) +\mathbb{E}(X_s^4).$$

Calculate the expectations on the right-hand side using the stationarity of the increments and the fact that $X_u$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $u$ for any $u \geq 0$.